# create identical R setup on multiple machines

Tags: r

I need to run a series of analyses on three servers and my laptop. In order to maintain the setup, I want each server to have identical packages (and versions) installed (incl. some of my own packages) as on my laptop. All of the packages and code has been developed and is installed the way I want it on my laptop (windows x64, Rstudio, R 3.4.3).

It would be easiest if I could simply copy the libraries folder from the laptop to the libraries folder on each servers, but does that work? Do I need to do anything else to have each server run exactly the same way as the R installation on my laptop?

Comment: Perhaps https://mran.microsoft.com/documents/rro/reproducibility is of interest to you. I haven't used it yet, though.

Comment: You can either copy library folder (not preferred) or use MRAN repository for the same date: [`checkpoint`](https://mran.microsoft.com/documents/rro/reproducibility). For the latest, you will only need to install your packages.

Comment: Maybe check out the RStudio `packrat ` package here : https://github.com/rstudio/packrat

Comment: @m0nhawk, why do you say it is not preferred to copy the library folder? Does it not (always) work, or is there another reason?

Comment: @SteveG.Jones Because in some rare cases for compiled packages it may not work, or worse, crash in runtime.